# awk - writing values from file

Tags: awk

How to write in awk a script that will write 10 values from the input file plase? Thank you.

I tried this:

```
BEGIN
$2 == 0 && $3 == 2  { print $7}
$2 == 0 && $3 == 4  { print $7}
$2 == 0 && $3 == 5  { print $7}
$2 == 2 && $3 == 2  { print $7}
$2 == 2 && $3 == 4  { print $7}
$2 == 2 && $3 == 5  { print $7}
$2 == 3 && $3 == 2  { print $7}
$2 == 3 && $3 == 4  { print $7}
$2 == 3 && $3 == 5  { print $7}
$1 == "achil" { print $3}
```

Should I write everything in one row?
When is it necessary to write BEGIN in code and when not?

Input file is:

```
 achil           1   197524.72437205614        197524.72437205614       0.43066284286002637     

o 0  1 0 1 1      5.732821000     
o 0  2 0 1 1  54002.804084586     
o 0  3 0 1 1      0.088300000    
o 0  4 0 1 1    150.924210421    
o 0  5 0 1 1    108.520740945     
o 0  6 0 1 1      0.380000000    
o 0  7 0 1 1      0.004220000    
o 0  8 0 1 1      0.000000000     
o 0  9 0 1 1      0.000000000    
o 0 10 0 1 1      0.000000000     
o 0 11 0 1 1      0.000000000     

o 2  1 0 1 1  73413.000000000     
o 2  2 0 1 1  36176.166543543     
o 2  3 0 1 1      0.560000000    
o 2  4 0 1 1    229.480202654     
o 2  5 0 1 1      7.032947038     
o 2  6 0 1 1      0.480000000     
o 2  7 0 1 1      0.000000000     
o 2  8 0 1 1      0.000000000     
o 2  9 0 1 1      0.000000000     
o 2 10 0 1 1      0.000000000    
o 2 11 0 1 1      0.000000000     

o 3  1 0 1 1    365.256360000     
o 3  2 0 1 1  51550.294729034     
o 3  3 0 1 1      0.016710220     
o 3  4 0 1 1    299.430719769    
o 3  5 0 1 1      0.001070537    
o 3  6 0 1 1      0.000036626    
o 3  7 0 1 1      0.000009111    
o 3  8 0 1 1      0.000000000    
o 3  9 0 1 1      0.000000000     
o 3 10 0 1 1      0.000000000    
o 3 11 0 1 1      0.000000000
```

I would like an output consisting of these 10 numbers:

```
197524.72437205614
54002.804084586
150.924210421
108.520740945
36176.166543543
229.480202654
7.032947038
51550.294729034
299.430719769
0.001070537
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The script you have is just about right, but you don't need the `BEGIN` clause when using it as a script. Because any actions you include in the `BEGIN` clause gets executed *before* any of the input lines are processed. For example consider a case when you had to print a title for your output, you can just print it as

```
BEGIN { print "my-title-string-in-double quotes" }
```

Writing it one line or in multiple lines is purely a matter of style and what you have looks neat and much readable. So all you need to do now is define a `awk` script with content as

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

$2 == 0 && $3 == 2  { print $7}
$2 == 0 && $3 == 4  { print $7}
$2 == 0 && $3 == 5  { print $7}
$2 == 2 && $3 == 2  { print $7}
$2 == 2 && $3 == 4  { print $7}
$2 == 2 && $3 == 5  { print $7}
$2 == 3 && $3 == 2  { print $7}
$2 == 3 && $3 == 4  { print $7}
$2 == 3 && $3 == 5  { print $7}
$1 == "achil"       { print $3}
```

Add execute permissions to it,

```
chmod +x script.awk
```

and run it as

```
awk -f script.awk input-file
```

But that said, your conditions could very well simply be written using pattern matching operators as

```
$2 ~ /^(0|2|3)$/ && $3 ~ /^(2|4|5)$/ { print $7; next } $1 == "achil" { print $3 }
```

Comment: Thank you and why is necessary to add execute permissions?

Comment: @Elisabeth it isn't. But you can run it like `./script.awk input-file` when it's executable.